# How to add two bi-vectors geometrically?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vectors, tensors

We know that how to add two vectors in the plan. i.e. The resultant of two vectors can be found using either the parallelogram method or the triangle method. For this we should place both vectors  at the same initial point (one dim less than vector dim).

[image]

I want to know how to add two bivectors in $\Bbb R^n$ geometrically? for example $v\wedge w+x\wedge y$. The first things come to my mind is that we should place these two bivectors with one edge in common,  then construct a parallelepiped with them and the plane through the diagonal of this parallelepiped is the wanted sum.

but I think one cannot always place two bivectors with one edge in common unless they have one common vector in their span. e.g. $v\wedge w$ and $w\wedge z$. Or perhaps my question is meaningless?

Comment: How do you visualize a bivector in the first place?

Comment: @Arthur: the plane spanned by its vectors, i.e. a parallelogram. But in Wikipedia, there is a circular bivectors that confused me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only decomposable $2$-vectors (i.e., ones that can be written as $v\wedge w$ for some vectors $v,w$) represent $2$-dimensional parallelograms/planes. The sum is an algebraic construction, not — sad to say for me — a geometric one. I mean, abstractly, in the vector space $\Lambda^2\Bbb R^n \cong \Bbb R^{n(n-1)/2}$, you are still adding vectors in a geometric way, but in general this says nothing about $2$-planes. Only when you have a sum of the form $v\wedge w + cv\wedge u = v\wedge (w+cu)$ will you get another decomposable $2$-vector as the sum.

(Here's a dimension count for you. As I indicated, the dimension of the vector space of bivectors is $n(n-1)/2$. The dimension of the Grassmannian of (oriented) $2$-planes in $\Bbb R^n$ is $2(n-2)$, and so if we add in one dimension for scalar multiples, we get $2n-3$, which is *less* than $n(n-1)/2$, unless $n=2$ or $3$.)

Comment: Thanks. Why Grassmannian elements are decomposable? (Not using its equivalent definition: set of decomposable bivectors of unite norm.)

Comment: As I said, any scalar multiple of the decomposable bivector $u\wedge v$ corresponds to the $2$-plane with basis $u,v$ and vice-versa. You can check that change of basis results in a scalar multiple of the original bivector.

Comment: I think "or $n=3$" (your last line) is  not geometric too. For example $e_1\wedge (e_2 +e_3)+e_2\wedge e_3$. Yeah?

Comment: My comment referred just to the dimension count. But your example is just the same as $(e_1+e_2)\wedge (e_2+e_3)$, so it is of course decomposable. That's all I was saying has to happen in dimension $3$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am careless.